# Ember data - access model ID field?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

In Ember, I need to store a model's ID in the session service. I'm not quite sure how to go about doing this, since IDs are seemingly not exposed and doing something like

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
    id                      : DS.attr('number'),
    loginname               : DS.attr('string'),
    /* ... */
});
```

gives an error:

Error: Assertion Failed: You may not set `id` as an attribute on your model. Please remove any lines that look like: `id: DS.attr('<type>')`

I need the model's ID persisted in the session along with all the other attributes, though.

**EDIT:**

I forgot to point out, that `console.log(this.get('session.user')`gives me this representation: `{loginname : 'foo', lastlogin, 'somedate', ...}` - no sign of any ID to be accessed, and `this.get('session.user.id')` returns `undefined`.

I'm on ember 2.3.0, ember-data 2.3.0

How can I achieve this? I'm thankful for any pointers!

Comment: Ember models have id key by default. If you use Ember Inspector, go to Data tab and see that all your models have ids persisted.

Comment: sorry, I should be more elaborate... the problem is that the object I query from the database and store in the session has no ID field I could access (see edit above)

Comment: I am going to assume that you are using ember-simple-auth. Session is stored in cookie or local store. Either way it can store only plain json. Not object from ember-data. The way around it is to save id into session and add computed property that would peek model from ember data store.

Comment: you are correct, but I suspect my problem is really with my understanding of ember data :) I authenticate with username/password against a REST service and after resolving the promise query another service for a user with these credentials. Now I get a valid user model object returned, but never see any ID. I will return with more code to clarify later.